# AWS WAF has no effect on apigateway behind cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, amazon-waf

I have a CloudFront distribution that points to an API gateway endpoint. I plugged a WAF ACL on that distribution and it seems to work.   When I access the API gateway endpoint using the CloudFront, I get blocked ( that's the desired behaviour that I configured on my ACL )

```
   https://<my-cloudfront-domain-name>/<my>/<api>/<endpoint> -> deny and I get a 403/blocked -> OK!
```

If I reach my endpoint "alone" ( not behind the cf distribution ) I can reach the endpoint normally. I wish to get blocked even if I reach the API in an isolated way

```
 https://<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<my>/<api>/<endpoint> -> passed and I get a 200 -> NOT OK...
```

My stack was built using the `serverless framework` and my API gateway is from `edge` type

Answer (score 4):

We had the exact same problem and contacted AWS support, and the support says Edge optimised APIs are fronted by a default CF distribution which the WAF is not able to recognise. To make WAF work for the default invoke URL you either need to change the endpoint type to Regional, or create a custom CF distribution.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway can restrict access by API key. CloudFront can send a custom, secret x-api-key header when it accesses the origin. The absence of that header in other requests to the API Gateway will cause API requests to be rejected with 403 Forbidden.

See Protecting your API using Amazon API Gateway and AWS WAF, parts [one](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-i/) and [two](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-2/).

Comment: My problem is that i follow the part one but i still can acess the api. If you verify part one, plugged a waf on a cf protected both apigateway and the cdn. On my scenario its fails. Part two requires an auth api - i wish to avoid it if i can.